# postgresql - Policy to prevent a field from being updated

Tags: postgresql, row-level-security, policy-based-management

How can I create a policy to prevent a field from being updated?

I am thinking something like this:

```sql
CREATE POLICY "test" ON posts.created_at FOR UPDATE WITH CHECK (exists(created_at));
```

Obviously this does not work, but I would like a way for this to work as long as there is no `created_at` coming into the UPDATE fields.

J

Comment: "*as long as there is no created_at coming into the UPDATE fields.*" - there is no way to detect if a specific column was specified in the UPDATE statement or not

Comment: ok, so it is impossible without a trigger I suppose.  Thanks!

Comment: I wrote an article on this after lots of research - https://code.build/p/XUPzns9ykZj4Abcazg1kt5/supabase-date-protection-trigger-functions

Answer (score 5):

This is indeed possible with a row-level security (RLS) policy by manually retrieving the old row and checking if your field's value would change between the old to the new row. A near-complete solution for this has been posted as [a Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71167428).

Several alternative solutions are also at your disposal:

- You can use a `BEFORE UPDATE` trigger, as you already mentioned. A Stack Overflow answer shows an [example for such a trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56083320).
- You can split your table into two tables, with a 1:1 relationship between them. Then, you can provide `SELECT` and `UPDATE` access to one table and only `SELECT` access to the other.
- You can provide `UPDATE` access to only a subset of columns of the table: `GRANT UPDATE(col1, col2)`. ([details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3281750))
- You can provide read-only access to the table and create a `VIEW` with the updateable columns of the table, and grant `UPDATE` access to that. Such a VIEW cannot have its own independent RLS policies, but if you need RLS, you can work around that in at least two ways:

  - re-using the RLS policies of the underlaying table via `security_invoker = on` ([details](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71573060)), while also using table-level permissions to prevent users from editing that underlaying table
  - creating a user-specific view that shows only the rows the user is allowed to edit ([details](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/301113)).
- You can hide the table behind a `FUNCTION` with `SECURITY DEFINER`. The table itself would not provide UPDATE access, instead users can only update the table through the `FUNCTION`.

(Inspired by [this list](https://github.com/supabase/supabase/discussions/656#discussioncomment-335362).)